# UIView animateWithDuration interfering with other CGRectMake

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, uiviewanimation

I have a `CGRectMake` that used to jump an image to a different position

```
image.frane=CGRectMake( x,y,w,h);
```

Then I wanted to translate and scale a `Label` (on the same `ViewController`) to another position

```
CGPoint newCenter = CGPointMake(x,y);
[UIView animateWithDuration: 1.0
    delay: 0
    options: 0
    animations:^{label.center = newCenter ; label.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 0.2, 0.2);}
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         label.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0);
                         label.alpha = 0;
    }
];
```

The problem I'm having is when I use the `animateWithDuration` the image doesn't move but the `Label` does. If I comment out the animation the image moves again. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: will you please elaborate your question and code.?

Comment: is `image.frane` a typo here?

Comment: Also is this an iOS6 app and are you using auto layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this bellow code...

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f animations:^{
    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(newCenter.x, newCenter.y, imageView.frame.size.width, imageView.frame.size.height);
}];
```

Also you can move `UIImageView` or anything else with this bellow code... i use this code for scroll the `UIScrollView` when keyboard appear.. i add the code with your requirement..

```
UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0f];
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(newCenter.x, newCenter.y, imageView.frame.size.width, imageView.frame.size.height);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

i hope this helpful to you...

Comment: Thanks that has them working. Although if I add the line to the setAnimation

    _label.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.2,0.2);

it stops working the first time again

Comment: What would be the best way of adding a scale to the CGRectMake? I haven't really used these before but it seems adjusting the frame width and height applies immediately not over time.

Comment: I'm looking to translate and scale a label at the same time so maybe from pos 100 100 to 200 200 and scale to 0.5 

The code

UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0f];
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(newCenter.x, newCenter.y, imageView.frame.size.width, imageView.frame.size.height);
[UIView commitAnimations];

Moves the object but it doesn't scale it right?

Comment: UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0f];
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(newCenter.x, newCenter.y, imageView.frame.size.width, imageView.frame.size.height);yourLable.frame = CGRectMake(200, 200, yourLable.frame.size.width, yourLable.frame.size.height);
[UIView commitAnimations];

Comment: @cantwelld use this above code just add that line for change the frame of lable

Comment: Thanks for the help but I'm still not getting where the scale happens here, the position is changed but the label.frame stays the same as does the transform. Running this code moves the label and the image but both remain the original size. 
The reason I was using label.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.5, 0.5); 
Is that it changes the scale.

Comment: just try it in second option of my code otherwise just search about CGAffineTransformMakeScale with example ... if not got it then post comment .. :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22553/discussion-between-paras-joshi-and-vishal)